# Using string for large number better than BIGINT? (postgresql)

Tags: python, postgresql, discord, discord.py, asyncpg

I'm working on a discord.py bot. I switching from sqlite3 to postgresql (specifically asyncpg) and I'm running into the error `value out of int32 range` when trying to store guild ids. I can solve this by using something like bigint, but I'm concerned about it taking up too much space? Would it be better to use a string instead?

[EDIT]: The numbers I'm using are 18 digits

Answer (score 1):

Use `bigint` by all means.

18 digit numbers fit well into a `bigint`, and it takes only 8 bytes. A string will at least take a byte per character plus one byte TOAST header.

Also, `bigint` comparisons are supported by the hardware and are way faster.

Comment: What happens when the integers exceed 20 digits

Comment: At some point you switch to `numeric`, thereby losing most of the advantages over `text` except type checking. Storage will still be more efficient than `text`.

Comment: Alright thanks. You said that "bigint comparisons are supported by the hardware and are way faster." Is that no longer true if I use the numeric type?

Comment: Right, `numeric` is binary coded decimal, and the code is written in C.